# How can I reference the content of a Class with other Class?

Tags: reference

I'm creating an appointment book. 
I created a class Day and a class AllTasks. 
The class AllTasks has a list of all the tasks that the user has created. 
The class Day has a list of all the tasks of that specific day.

My question is:

How can I reference for each Day the Tasks included in the AllTasks? Or if there is a best way to do it.

Is there a way that if I delete a Task from AllTasks is automatically deleted from the Day that have this Task too?

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you post your code, or at least, the class definitions?

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define an attribute, say allTasks as an array of objects of class AllTasks in the class Day. Add getter, setter and constructor.